# What is wrong with my sizeof operator?

Tags: visual-studio-code, sizeof

I tried sizeof operator (VS code, Mac)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char i;
    int  j;
    double k;

    printf("%d\n", sizeof(i));
    printf("%d\n", sizeof(j));
    printf("%d\n", sizeof(k));

    return 0;
}
```

but the warning says:

```
warning: format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'unsigned long' [-Wformat]
printf("%d\n", sizeof(k)); 
        %lu
```

What is wrong? I think there's nothing wrong with the syntax and it shows me output.

Comment: Is this a C++ question, or C or something else? Please add language tag.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is wrong with the sizeof operator.
You are using the wrong specifier for [printf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf).

[sizeof](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof) returns a [size_t](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t).
The actual type of a size_t is implementation defined.
As such, `%z` is correct specifier for printing size_t

Use `printf("%zu\n", sizeof(k));`

Comment: I'm not sure if Microsoft supports `%zu`, so if that doesn't work then another option is `printf("%d\n", (int)sizeof i);`

Comment: It also looks like OP's compiler is suggesting `%lu`.

Comment: "%zu", "%lu" and "(int)sizeof" are all working for me. Thanks.

Comment: " %d\n, sizeof(k)" doesn't work in Xcode as well. Is that working just in visual studio or why so many tutorials say to use it?